# How to update only field in drf

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to update a field of my model, im trying use patch for this, but i'm new to django rest and i think i'm having something wrong

Im try use partial_update method but doesn't work. I want update status for canceled(canceled is in my enums.py )

This is part of my model

```py
class Aula(AcademicoBaseModel, permissions.AulaPermission):
    turma_disciplina = models.ForeignKey(TurmaDisciplina, models.PROTECT, related_name='lessons')
    data_inicio = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    data_termino = models.DateTimeField()
    duracao = models.IntegerField(default=50)
    status = models.ForeignKey('Status', models.PROTECT, default=1)
```

This is my view

```py
class CancelLessonView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.AulaSerializer

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        lesson = self.kwargs.get('id')
        instance = models.Aula.objects.get(id=lesson)
        instance.status_id = enums.StatusEnum.CANCELLED

        serializer = serializers.AulaSerializer(data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        instance.save()


        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This my model Status

```py
class Status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='nome')
    color = models.CharField(max_length=7, db_column='cor')
    ignore_in_attendance_report = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    allow_attendances = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    allow_activities = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

My enums.py

```py
class StatusEnum:
    NOT_SENT = 1
    PENDING = 2
    SENT = 3
    CONTENT_PENDING = 4
    CANCELLED = 5
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `instance.status = enums.StatusEnum.CANCELLED` ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I suggest always use English names - it will be much easier to understand Your code for other programmers.

Regarding status, if You want really simple solution I suggest to change status to simple boolean field, and You can use instance.status = False or True.

Why You use ForeignKey to Status? How Status model looks like?

### EDIT

My practice is to add services.py file to each django app, where I create service, in Your example lets say AulaService. In this class You can define method:

```
# lesson == Aula
update_lesson_status(self, lesson_id, status_id):
  Aula.objects.filter(id=lesson_id).update(status_id=status_id)
```

and You can use service anywhere (but first remember to import service),
in Your example You can call service in view:

```
class CancelLessonView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.AulaSerializer

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        lesson = self.kwargs.get('id')
        AulaService().update_lesson_status(lesson_id=lesson,
                                  status_id=enums.StatusEnum.CANCELLED
```

Cheers,
Fenrir

Comment: thanks buddy, im sorry i forgot change names in pt before send. My model status was a model that had been around for a while, I'm in a big project that I already got underway.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Please add Status model and I will try to help You :)

Comment: I add Status model in ask